# Problem: Daemon failed to start. Timed out, local node is not responding after 120 seconds

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

Unable to sync Monero GUI version 0.17.1.9  and Ledger nano s ver 1.6.1. wallet
I'm trying to sync GUI version: 0.17.1.9-release, in Advanced mode (Local node).

These are the steps taken to sync GUI wallet:

1. Launch Monero Desktop app
2. Put in 8 PIN to Ledger Nano s running firmware version 1.6.1
3. Typed in Monero wallet password
4. Get message "Opening Wallet" and
5. answer Export View key question on Nano s
6. Get message "Starting Local Node"
7. Network Status: Starting the node
8. Then I get "Daemon Failed to start
   Timed out, local node is not responding after 120 secs

I upgraded from GUI version: 0.17.1.7 to GUI version: 0.17.1.8 to version: 0.17.1.9. "--enable-dns-blocklist" was typed in Daemon Startup flags a few attempts ago.

The app has not worked since about 30 December, at GUI version: 0.17.1.7.

The daemon log shows.....:
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

[06/01/2021 15:34] 2021-01-06 15:34:43.853 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.8-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

[06/01/2021 15:34] 2021-01-06 15:34:49.681 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.8-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

[06/01/2021 15:35] 2021-01-06 15:35:01.367 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.8-release) Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081 ......... and so on

Suspecting the Wallet is corrupt I followed the CLI manual monerod process in an earlier answer to another user who couldn't sync. The process started to sync manually. After 10 hours I typed in EXIT  in CLI and tried the GUI wallet assuming corruption had been fixed. Still unable to sync GUI wallet and getting same error message:  Daemon failed to start. Timed out, local node is not responding after 120 seconds. Please advise how to fix my Windows desktop wallet.

Comment: Can you describe your issue in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Update to the new version 0.17.1.8 and use —enable-dns-blocklist

Answer (score 0):

data.mdb was corrupted giving me the issues above.
Started to restore wallet by deleting corrupted data.mdb. It was going to take about 20 days to restore so followed advise found in blog re using SSD. Installed external SSD and moved folder that contains Blockchain as outlined in earlier blog. Copied data.mdb from HDD to SSD and wallet works perfectly. Many thanks to earlier blogger who recommended moving to SSD.